# mysql search speed between join and union and/or other

Tags: php, mysql, join, union, multiple-tables

I am trying to create a search functionality where users would type a word or key phrase and then information is displayed.

I was thinking of using the LEFT JOIN to add all the table i need to be searchable,someone has told me about `UNION` and I have a hunch that it may be slower than `JOIN`

so

```
$query = '
SELECT * 
FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t2 
    ON t2.content = "blabla"
  LEFT JOIN t3
    ON t3.content = "blabla"
  [...]
WHERE t1.content =  "blabla"
';
```

Is the above a good practice or is there a better approach i should be looking into ?

Send me on the right path for this :) also argue why its wrong, argue why you think your approach is better so it will help me and other understand this:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it's a bad idea to play hunches to "guess" what the performance of an SQL engine will be like.  There is very sophisticated optimization happening in there which takes into account the size of the tables, the availability of indexes, the cardinality of indexes, and so on.

In this example, LEFT JOIN is wrong because you're producing a semi-cartesian JOIN.  Basically, there will be a *lot* more rows in your result set than you think.  That's because each matching row in t1 will be joined with each matching row in t2.  If ten rows match in t1 and three in t2, you will not get ten results but thirty.

Even if only one row is guaranteed to match from each table (eliminating the cartesian join problem) it's clear that the LEFT JOIN solution will give you a dataset that's very hard to work with.  That's because the content columns from each of the tables you JOIN will be *separate* columns in the result set.  You'll have to examine each of the columns to figure out which table matched.

In this case, UNION is a better solution.

Also, please note:

1. Use of "*" in SELECT is generally not a good idea.  It reduces performance (because all columns must be assembled in the result set) and in a case like this you lose the opportunity to ALIAS each of the content columns, making the result set harder to work with.
2. This is a very novel use of LEFT JOIN.  Normally, it's used to associate rows from two different tables.  In this case you're using it to produce three separate result sets "side-by-side".  Most SQL programmers will have to look at this statement cross-eyed for a while to figure out what your intent was.

Comment: oh no i simplified everything there :) it was an example sql, also I dnt use `*` at all but each table will have a title, content field and a couple common fields and thats where I will be searching and ignoring the rest. I am still in a cross road here and don't know what would be the best way to handle a multi-table searching

Comment: Well, unless your example is structured differently from your simplified example, all the objections I listed to the LEFT JOIN approach will still apply.